# Nhibernate join on a table twice

Tags: c#, nhibernate, eager-loading, criteria-api, detachedcriteria

Consider the following Class structure...

```
public class ListViewControl
{
    public int SystemId {get; set;}
    public List<ControlAction> Actions {get; set;}
    public List<ControlAction> ListViewActions {get; set;}
}

public class ControlAction
{
    public string blahBlah {get; set;}
}
```

I want to load class ListViewControl **eagerly** using NHibernate.
The mapping using Fluent is as shown below

```
public UIControlMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.SystemId);
        HasMany(x => x.Actions)
            .KeyColumn("ActionId")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .AsBag()
            .Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();
        HasMany(x => x.ListViewActions)
            .KeyColumn("ListViewActionId")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .AsBag()
            .Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();
    }
```

This is how I am trying to load it eagerly

```
var baseActions = DetachedCriteria.For<ListViewControl>()
            .CreateCriteria("Actions", JoinType.InnerJoin)                
            .SetFetchMode("BlahBlah", FetchMode.Eager)
            .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());

var listViewActions = DetachedCriteria.For<ListViewControl>()
            .CreateCriteria("ListViewActions", JoinType.InnerJoin)
            .SetFetchMode("BlahBlah", FetchMode.Eager)
            .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());

var listViews = DetachedCriteria.For<ListViewControl>()
            .SetFetchMode("Actions", FetchMode.Eager)
            .SetFetchMode("ListViewActions",FetchMode.Eager)
            .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());

var result = _session.CreateMultiCriteria()
                .Add("listViewActions", listViewActions)
                .Add("baseActions", baseActions)
                .Add("listViews", listViews)
                .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
                .GetResult("listViews");
```

Now, my problem is that the class `ListViewControl` get the correct records in both `Actions` and `ListViewActions`, but there are multiple entries of the same record. The number of records is equal to the number of joins made to the `ControlAction` table, in this case two.

How can I avoid this? If I remove the `SetFetchMode` from the `listViews` query, the actions are loaded lazily through a proxy which I don't want.

I also tried creating aliases ...

```
.SetFetchMode("Actions", FetchMode.Eager)
.CreateAlias("Actions","actions",JoinType.RightOuterJoin)
.SetFetchMode("ListViewActions",FetchMode.Eager)
.CreateAlias("ListViewActions", "liactions", JoinType.RightOuterJoin)
```

This removed the duplicate entries, but did not eagerly load

Comment: you should always language-tag your questions.

Answer (score 0):

That's an extremely inefficient way to eager load collections. Here's a better way:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/16/eagerly-loading-entity-associations-efficiently-with-nhibernate.aspx

Comment: I thought I was using the same mechanism... http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/04/06/eager-loading-aggregate-with-many-child-collections.aspx
The URL you provided and the one I gave load collections for a single entity object. I want to retrieve all objects.
Have a look at this URL as well
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839357/load-collections-eagerly-in-nhibernate-using-criteria-api