# How to join multiple 1 to many relationship tables using NHibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have the following tables:

1. Application
2. Component
3. Position

An Application can have 1 to many Components
An Application can have 1 to many Positions.

When I try to run a join using NHibernate like this:

```
IEnumerable<Application> applications = Session.Query<Application>()
    .FetchMany(r => r.Components)
    .FetchMany(r => r.Positions)
```

and I look at the positions list it has duplicate positions. This goes away if I remove the first `FetchMany()`:

```
IEnumerable<Application> applications = Session.Query<Application>()
    .FetchMany(r=>r.Positions)
```

I thought NHibernate takes care of normalizing your collections when doing multiple 1 to many joins but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any suggestions or workarounds on how to allow me to do multiple 1 to many joins using NHibernate LINQ without getting these duplicate records?

Comment: Is there any relationship between Components and Positions?

Comment: this answer may be of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295837/nhibernate-problem-eager-loading-two-child-collections-one-being-a-component-li/2297156#2297156

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a solution, but a workaround that performs better than a solution.

Seperate queries will probably perform better than one big query because they retrieve less data. You can execute the separate queries at once by using `.Future()`

One large result set with 2 Apps with 2 components and 2 positions = 24 elements

```
ApplicationColumns ComponentColumns PositionColumns
AppA               ColA             PosA
AppA               ColB             PosA
AppA               ColA             PosB
AppA               ColB             PosB   
AppB               ColC             PosC
AppB               ColD             PosC
AppB               ColC             PosD
AppB               ColD             PosD
```

Three small result sets with 2 Apps with 2 components and 2 positions = 10 elements

```
ApplicationColumns
AppB
AppB

ComponentColumns
ColA
ColB
ColC
ColD

PositionColumns
PosA
PosB
PosC
PosD
```

Select N+1 and outer join are not the only choice.

Comment: thanks as i appreciate your points above. when you run multiple queries using future, how do you get it back together as a single object graph as i want to display a table that shows a single row with appName, component info and position info.

Comment: When the objects are associated, the object-graphs are created automatically in memory by NHiberante. I guess 2 queries (increases the result to 16 elements) will work the best for the descibed situation: Load apps with columns fetched and Load apps with positions fetched.

Comment: i still dont quite follow.  In this case you would get two results back (one for each query).  Each result would be a list of Apps (one would include a full join to components and one would include a full join to positions).  if i want to do a loop through the app list and pull out both component and position information are you saying that nhibernate will allow both results to read both component info and position info without going back to the database ??

Comment: Yes, once the collections are loaded, no queries need to be executed. You might need to distinct on the list of Apps. It does not matter which list of apps you return, they both should reference the same instances.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at result transformers. You should be able to add this to your query and have it get rid of the duplicate entries.

```
SetResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DistinctRootEntity)
```

You should also be able to leave the FetchMany methods out if you want to use lazy-loading. It could cause many queries to be run, however.

Comment: i want to avoid lazy loading because of the multiple queries

Comment: Ah ok, the Transformer should still prevent lazy-loading, although I'm not 100% sure. Try it out and let me know.